# Methods for allowing restricted access to web applications

Tags: web-application

Since I'm fully aware that allowing access for anybody to open web hosting control panel (login page), can be a little bit risky, I started to think about restricting access and allowing only for my users, but I'm not sure which method should I use.

I was thinking about IP restriction, but dynamic IP can be a problem, then proxy or VPN is also kind of solution, so any other ideas?

P.S. This issue is not only related to cpanel, but also for other web applications, where restriction should play a role.

I'm also planning to hide URL like in this example: `https://website.com/51ca673ea8e89a868706fd309777a101ac63a409/phpmyadmin`

Comment: Why do you think that the login page is insecure?

Comment: Client certs. Forget about weird URLs, and limit login attempts.

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html#allclients

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest more VPN as some inside-webserver solution. The reason is, the problem of the authentication and encryption belongs to this specific software, while webservers have to fulfill a lot of other criteria, too. Calculating the working hours / security I would vote a VPN solution.

You have to solve 2 tasks:

1. authentication
2. encryption

Although the authentication part can be made also in the webserver. In this case, we can see the 3 points of the authentication:

1. what you are
2. what you have
3. what you know

I suspect you don't have too much control over your users, and over their systems. Thus (1) falls out. You can think on (2), i.e. on some hardware key-based authentication. In the case (3), you can use either the good old passwords, or some more tricky way (for example: one time password sent by sms).

On the encryption side: the VPN solves it. On HTTPS, it is not so easy. Use strong encryption algorithms with properly configured and authorized certs.